# Create an arrayformula that find word

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to find a formula with arrayformula that will search a specific word on many columns and report an anwser. So in my exemple below, if a row show need order, it will tell *need order* in the arrayformula column and if not it will show *ok*.

| =arrayformula | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| need order | $ 20 | need order |
| ok | $ 60 | $100$ |

I've tried to used the formula below wiht arrayformula but couldn't find a way to make it work.

=IF(COUNTIF(B2:C3,"*need order*")>0,"need order","ok")

I'm open to all suggestion
Cheers

Comment: could there be a "need order" in colum B as well? or only in C like in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming GS, try something along the lines of:

```
=BYROW(FILTER(B:C,B:B<>""),LAMBDA(a,IF(COUNTIF(a,"need order"),"need order","ok")))
```

In case of headers, try:

```
=BYROW(FILTER(B2:C,B2:B<>""),LAMBDA(a,IF(COUNTIF(a,"need order"),"need order","ok")))
```

Comment: Aswome, that did work. What I haven't told is that I wanted the formula in my header, and that I wanted to show header title, so I've you formula like this:

=arrayformula(IF(B9:B="Dealer","Status",BYROW(FILTER(G9:R,G9:G<>""),LAMBDA(a,IF(COUNTIF(a,"need order"),"need order","ok")))))

Let me know if you think of a error here but it's look like it's work

Comment: @AlexAuthentik, I am not sure I understand what your need is.

Comment: no worries, after revising it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help!